# modrewrite how can all files to index.php?

Tags: .htaccess, webserver

actual .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule index.php [L]
```

target:
All files should point to index.php
also png/xml ect.

call on browser:
http://localhost:8080/test.png

browser message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiWYG.png)

log:

```
[Sun Feb  6 01:23:29 2022] [::1]:57052 Accepted
[Sun Feb  6 01:23:29 2022] [::1]:57052 [404]: GET /test.png - No such file or directory
[Sun Feb  6 01:23:29 2022] [::1]:57052 Closing
```

my server start to test with:

php -S localhost:8080 -dxdebug.mode=debug -dxdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1 -dxdebug.client_port=9003 -dxdebug.start_with_request=yes

my actual server:

```
PHP 8.1.1 (cli) (built: Dec 17 2021 22:38:05) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.1, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.1, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

works on macbook ...

have an idea to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

> PHP 8.1.1 (cli) (built: Dec 17 2021 22:38:05) (NTS)

You are using the built-in PHP webserver. `.htaccess` (and by extension mod_rewrite) is an Apache config file and is not supported by the PHP webserver.

To implement a front-controller/router using the PHP built-in webserver you need to use PHP, as described in the PHP docs:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

---

*Aside:* The mod_rewrite rule is also incorrect and won't work as written:

> ```
> RewriteRule index.php [L]
> ```

You are missing the first argument to the `RewriteRule` directive, so it will never match the request you are making. It should be something like this:

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Where `.` (a single dot) is a regular expression (*pattern*) that matches at least 1 character (ie. everything except the document root, which is handled by the `DirectoryIndex`).

Further Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

---

> works on MacBook ...

You must be using Apache, with a different `.htaccess` file!